# VBA EXCEL fixed range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code for callculating covariance Matrix

```
'covariance Matrix

Set rngInput = wsReturns.Range("$B$1:$L$457")
Set rngOutPut = wsModel.Range("$A$14")

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Mcovar", rngInput, _
    rngOutPut, "C", True
```

However the number of rows and columns of source data may change. (For example last cell may be not L457 but N800 and so on)

I've tried to do this via this code but this does not work

```
dataLastColumn = wsReturns.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
dataLastRow = wsReturns.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rngInput = wsReturns.Range("$B$1" & dataLastColumn & dataLastRow)
Set rngOutPut = wsModel.Range("$A$14")

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Mcovar", rngInput, _
    rngOutPut, "C", True
```

Comment: Try `Set rngInput = wsReturns.Range("B1", wsReturns.Cells(dataLastRow, dataLastColumn))`.

Comment: dataLastColumn and dataLastRow will bring you numerical values, so  "$B$1" & dataLastColumn & dataLastRow" (for N800) will bring you B114800 as range, instead of B1:N800)